# Find last occurrence of a max value in a row and get Column name in Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe called df:

| Id | Stage1 | Stage2 | Stage3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2020-04-03 | 2022-06-07 |
| --- | ------------ | ------------ | ----------- |
| 2 | 2023-06-07 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-09-03 |
| --- | ------------ | ------------ | ----------- |
| 3 | 2023-02-04 | 2023-06-07 | 2022-06-07 |
| --- | ------------ | ------------ | ----------- |
| 4 | 2022-05-08 | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-01 |

I need to calculate the max date for each ID and its respective Stage. So for Order 1,2,3,4 the Stages I need are Stage 3, Stage 1, Stage 2, and Stage 3 respectively. I understand that using

```
df.filter(like="stage").idxmax(axis=1)
```

Finds the first occurrence of max date in a row and gives me its column name. However, for Order 4, Stage 2 and 3 have the same date. I need Stage 3 as my answer as Stage 3 is the latest stage of the order. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap order of columns for match latest maximal value:

```
s = df.filter(like="Stage").iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)
print (s)
0    Stage3
1    Stage1
2    Stage2
3    Stage3
dtype: object
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.filter(like="Stage").iloc[:, ::-1])
      Stage3     Stage2     Stage1
0 2022-06-07 2020-04-03 2022-02-01
1 2020-09-03 2020-03-01 2023-06-07
2 2022-06-07 2023-06-07 2023-02-04
3 2023-09-01 2023-09-01 2022-05-08
```